# Mage registry key "_singleton/customer/session

Tags: magento

I have created magento custom module using [this](http://silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/).In this module I'm trying to use customer_save_after event.Everything was perfect but the problem came when I merged created module files with local magento. Its throwing error like Mage registry key "_singleton/customer/session" already exists.I have cleared cache and every thing but still error was not solved.Can anyone suggest me the solution for this?

Here is the error code:

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:62:"Mage registry key "_singleton/customer/session" already exists";i:1;s:2302:"#0 /var/www/dev/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
    #1 /var/www/dev/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/cust...', false)
    #2 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(520): Mage::getSingleton('customer/sessio...')
    #3 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php(141): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->getSummaryQty()
    #4 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php(46): Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart->getSummaryCount()
    #5 [internal function]: Mage_Checkout_Block_Links->addCartLink()
    #6 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #7 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #8 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #9 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #10 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
    #11 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #12 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
    #13 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
    #14 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
    #15 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #16 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #17 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #18 /var/www/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #19 /var/www/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:5:"/dev/";s:11:"script_name";s:14:"/dev/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This because you already registered the same key name _singleton/customer/session.

**#File: app/Mage.php**// you can see below function in this file

```
public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        self::throwException('Mage registry key "'.$key.'" already exists');
    }
    self::$_registry[$key] = $value;
}
```

We can see that any object or value we’re storing in the registry is ultimately being stored in the static **$_registry** class variable. We can also see that before storing the value, Magento checks if it’s already set. If so, Magento will either throw an Exception (the default behavior) or gracefully return null

its already set with other value

Finally, if you want to make you variable unavailable, you can use the unregister method to remove it from the registry.

```
Mage::unregister('some_name');
```

hope this help you

Comment: some_name means what? How I check which same key is already registered?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to rename `<module> folder` located in `App/Code/Codepool/`, I got the same Error.

Looks like the name you mentioned in the xml(`app/etc/modules/<somemodule.xml>`) doesn't match with the Module Folders located in the `CodePool`.

Renaming the `Module Folder` as Registered in the `xml file`, will resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

In the magento folder from the shell:

```
php -f compiler.php clear
php -f compiler.php disable
```

this will disable the compilation and will clear the files, after this delete content of var/cache/* and var/session/* by this command:

```
rm -Rf var/cache/*
rm -Rf var/session/*
```

Also try do disable the module in app/etc/modules/module.xml